# How to install annotate gem with bundler 1.15.4 with rails 2.2.4 without updating bundler/rails versions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

Would like to implement the annotate gem with bundler 1.15.4 and rails 2.2.4. But gives me the error below:

```
Could not find gem 'bundler (~> 1.15.4)', which is required by gem 'rails (>=
3.0)', in any of the relevant sources: the local ruby installation
```

I can't update the bundler or rails versions due to work constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much can't, unless you install the first tagged release of `annotate`, which is over 6 years old.

If you go even one tagged version newer, it depends on `ActiveRecord >= 2.3`, which you don't have on version 2.2.4 of Rails.